# OV Code Signing Certification - Gather Reputation Time

Tags: windows, code-signing, software-distribution, code-signing-certificate

I purchased a OV code signing certificate in aug 2020. Since then the software is still marked as malicious in Windows Defender. Do you know how long it usually takes to gather the reputation and get rid of Windows Defender message?

[image]

[image]